# Spring Boot - @Configuration class is null in spring component

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a problem with spring boot when using autowired on a configuration class.
I have minimized the problem by creating a small [spring boot project](https://github.com/Hatta84/Spring-Boot-Test) on github.

I created the *MyBean* class declaring it as *@Component* and attempting the autowired of the *MyConf* class which is declared as *@Configuration* (and reads the property in the file myconfig.properties). In theory, everything is in the spring context, but when the application starts *myConfigProp* variable in MyBean is null.

Where am I wrong?

I also tried the following solutions, all not working:

- Insert the *@DependsOn* in MyBean
- Commented on the *@Component* and configured MyBean as *@Bean* of spring

The last test I did (not present on github project) was to pass MyConfigProp as a parameter in MyBean constructor, and it worked.

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

    String message;

    public MyBean(MyConfigProp myConfigProp) {
        this.message = myConfigProp.getMessage();
    }

}
```

I am somewhat confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're not Autowiring MyConfigProp's into MyBean:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

String message;

    @Autowired
    public MyBean(MyConfigProp myConfigProp) {
        this.message = myConfigProp.getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: We don't really need `@Autowired` annotation when we do construction auto-loading.

Comment: It seems the only working solution, however `@Autowired` make no difference. Unfortunately I still don't understand why this is the only solution

Comment: @Johna You're right, I wasn't aware this feature had been introduced. More specifically, you don't need Autowired on single parameter constructors since spring 4.3. And yet for some reason adding it fixes the problem ???

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfigProp.class)` in your `MyBean` class so that it looks like:

`MyBean.java`

```java
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfigProp.class)
public class MyBean {

String message;

    @Autowired
    public MyBean(MyConfigProp myConfigProp) {
        this.message = myConfigProp.getMessage();
    }

}
```

`MyConfigProp.java`

```java
@PropertySource("classpath:myconfig.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
public class MyConfigProp {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: @EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfigProp.class) make no difference

Comment: Remove the `@Configuration` at the following line: https://github.com/Hatta84/Spring-Boot-Test/blob/bf88a557fbd46d398b7078927c4e4af2f7704dd7/demo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/conf/MyConfigProp.java#L7

Comment: Nope wrong again. If you check the code out you can test this before posting.

Comment: @MichaelW I checked the code out and tested this, the code worked with the first modification, adding the `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfigProp.class)` as suggested above. The second suggestion was because I suspected that Spring could have issues with `@Configuration` as it essentially a component that produces Beans for the context and this was not producing Beans, it was binding properties.

Comment: @MichaelW you also do not need `@Autowired` when using constructor injection, Spring knows to Autowired in that instance ;)

Comment: It seems the only working solution, however `@Autowired` make no difference and `@EnableConfigurationProperties` can be removed if you leave `@Configuration` on `MyConfiProp`

Comment: @Hattawhich solution is the working solution? Yes, `@Autowired` will not make a difference in constructor injection. I take it you've tried without the annotations you are claiming to be redundant?

Comment: @FanaSithole sorry for the delay, missing space near the nick had not sent me the notification. Yes, I tried removing all the notes and the only working solution is to pass `MyConfigProp` as a parameter in `MyBean` constructor as from post even without `@Autowired` (as suggested by @Johna). I think I understand why between documentation and evidence, I'm about to answer.

Comment: @Hatta no problem then :)

Comment: Thanks, @FanaSithole , i had a similar issue but by adding PropertySource annotation on MyConfig class my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions and the only one that actually solve the problem is to pass `MyConfigProp` as a parameter in `MyBean` constructor, as from post, even without `@Autowired`.

[**Code update**](https://github.com/Hatta84/Spring-Boot-Test)

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

  String message;

  public MyBean (MyConfigProp myConfigProp) {
     this.message = myConfigProp.getMessage ();
  }
}
```

I share the rest for knowledge.
In detail, trying the proposed solutions, the result was:

- Adding the `@Component` `stereo-type` on `MyConfigProp` annotation to
  use `@Autowired` in `MyBean` not work, even adding `@ComponentScan`. It still launches `NullPointerException`
- The annotation `@EnableConfigurationProperties` seems to be useful only if
  `@Configuration` is not used on `MyConfigProp` and does not solve the problem

From the tests and the documentation readings, if I understand correctly, the problem is that I try to use the object in `@ Autowired` in the`MyBean` constructor and, during the creation of this, `Spring` has not yet instantiated`MyConfigProp`, hence the`NullPointerException`.
I updated the [code](https://github.com/Hatta84/Spring-Boot-Test) by adding a `solutions` `package` with the possible solutions:

- `MyBeanWorked`: Solution shown above.
- `WithoutConstructor`: By moving the instruction into a method, the
  startup is successful and the application works.
- `WorkedWithInjectProp`: Not declared as `@Component` but configured as
  `@Bean`. A little longer but, needing only a property, perhaps cleaner.

More details in the code. 
I hope I have done something pleasant.